# Why we need to store the receipt of In App Payment from Apple to server?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have tested and seems there is no need to store the receipt to complete the payment flow.

So what is the real purpose of the receipt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of the receipt is for your server to ***verify*** the validity of the transaction with apple should you so desire and, as @Daniel put it short and sweet, book keeping.

Answer (score 2):

Jailbroken phones are everywhere, and some of them are enabling user to successfully complete in-app purchase without any real connection to Apple server, by replacing original API with dummy one that return fake receipt. By that, you should get the idea already how receipt and the receipt verification is useful.